# @react-navigation/native upgrade to V5 SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am having some trouble with upgrading my react-navigation from v3 to v5. I keep running into this error, at first I thought it was a bug but I am not finding any other complaints online about it. To be 100% sure the old versions weren't causing any issues, I completely uninstalled all react-navigation and started from scratch with v5. I am still getting an error with the index file. It doesn't appear to understand the typescript...is this a known bug? Is there another step I need to take that is not in the documentation about installing Typescript?

UPDATE:
./types files is not compiling correctly...it doesn't seem to recognize NavigationState or ActionHelpers...is this a bug? Has anyone seen this before?

UPDATE 2
i am running on RN V0.59 so I am thinking there could be a dependency issue. I am upgrading to V0.62.2 and seeing if the issue persists

[image]

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

[image]

> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/myusername/myprojectname/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/src/index.tsx:
>   Unexpected token (51:12)
>
> 49 |  * Types   50 |  */
>
> > 51 | export type {
> >          |             ^   52 |   StackNavigationOptions,   53 |   StackNavigationProp,   54 |   StackHeaderProps,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use TypeScript, do this:

- Delete `node_modules` and the lock file (`yarn.lock` or `package.lock`)
- Upgrade TypeScript to latest i.e. 3.8.3.
- Run `yarn cache clean` or `npm cache clean`.
- Run `yarn` or `npm install`.
- Run `yarn react-native start --reset-cache`.
- Run `yarn react-native run-android`.

If you don't, then follow these steps:

- Run `yarn add --dev @babel/core@^7.9.0 @babel/runtime@^7.9.0`.
- Uninstall apk from `emulator/phone`.
- Run `yarn react-native start --reset-cache`.
- Run `yarn react-native run-android`.

If that did not work, go to `android/`, and run `gradlew clean` or `./gradlew clean`, remove the apk from you phone and rerun `yarn react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helps you!

Delete your **yarn.lock** or **package-json.lock** file and run **yarn/npm install**.

Then try clearing cache with **npx react-native start --reset-cache** or **expo start -c**

**References**

[Upgrade](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#im-getting-syntaxerror-in-react-navigationxxxxxxtsx-or-syntaxerror-xxxreact-navigationxxxxxxtsx-unexpected-token)

[Cache clear](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#stale-cache-of-metro-bundler)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who can't get it to work by removing `node_modules` and whatnot:

Add `@babel/core` as a **global** dependency (`yarn global add @babel/core` / `npm install -g @babel/core`), because globally-installed `expo-cli` won't recognize project-based babel installations for some reason.